# How to get row count of dynamic Excel (excluding header) using nightwatch

Tags: loops, count, rows, nightwatch.js, nightwatch

I want to print the number of rows present in Excel (this is a dynamic number) and with that row count. I do not want the header being included. This is what I tried until now:

[image]

Comment: If you want to ignore the header in your count, can't you just do records - 1?

Comment: Yes, it works if I change the code to :
"var records = Sheet.rowCount-1;
 console.log("Total Records:" + records)"


Thanks!